# Find the last occurrence of a number in a string, and split the string by that value

Tags: c#, regex, split

What I am trying to accomplish is finding the last number in a string and split by that value.

```
string packageSize = "4/8.75LB";
```

Above I have a string that I would like to split into a string array, and put those into two different columns in the database. The first part would be a decimal, and the last part would be a string or varchar.

I have this code below and it seems to be working. Just wondering if there is a better solution, or an answered question that I missed.

```
string value = Regex.Match(packageSize, @"(\d+)(?!.*\d)", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).ToString();
int lastIndex = packageSize.LastIndexOf(value) + value.Length;
string packageLoad = packageSize.Substring(0, lastIndex);
decimal loadDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(packageLoad);
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var output = Regex.Split(packageSize, @"(\d)(?=\D*$)");
```

The `(\d)(?=\D*$)` regex matches and captures a digit with `(\d)` that is also returned with `Regex.Split` (it outputs captured substrings). The `(?=\D*$)` makes sure the `(\d)` matches the last digit in the string.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/qXuh2N):

```cs
var packageSize = "4/8.75LB";
var result = Regex.Split(packageSize, @"(\d)(?=\D*$)");
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);

// => 4/8.7
//    5
//    LB
```

If you need to make sure the regex split actually occurred, check if the length of the output array is not equal to `1`:

```cs
var packageSize = "4/8.75LB";
//var packageSize = "LB"; // => 'LB' did not match the regex.
var result = Regex.Split(packageSize, @"(\d)(?=\D*$)");
if (result.GetLength(0) != 1) { // We have found a match
    foreach (var s in result)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"'{packageSize}' did not match the regex.");
}
```

See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/vkS3cq).

**Also**, if you need to only match ASCII digits, use `Regex.Split(packageSize, @"(\d)(?=\D*$)", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)`.

Answer (score 3):

> "I want to find the last digit, and split the string into two either side of it"

Performance-wise I don't think you'll do much better than a loop:

```
for(int i = str.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
  if(Char.IsDigit(str[i])){
    return (str[..i], str[(i+1)..]);
  }
```

It returns a tuple of `("4/8.7", "LB")`

--

You could jiggle that to one of:

```
var i = str.LastIndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());

var i = Array.FindLastIndex(str.ToCharArray(), Char.IsDigit);

return (str[..i], str[(i+1)..]);
```

What puzzles me is that the spec you're giving in the comments is nothing like the code you're giving in the question.. Your code "works" but there's no way that `4/8.7` would `Convert.ToDecimal`..

Answer (score 2):

You could use 2 capture groups for the first part before and the second part after matching the last digit.

If  you want to match at least a single char per group, change the quantifier to `+` instead of `*`

```
^(.*)[0-9](\D*)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(.*)` Capture group 1, match any char
- `[0-9]` Match a single digits 0-9
- `(\D*)` Capture group 2, optionally match non digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q5wfBz/1)

For example

```
string packageSize = "4/8.75LB";
Regex r = new Regex(@"^(.*?)[0-9](\D*)$");
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(packageSize))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Output

```
4/8.7
LB
```

Comment: `(.*)\d(\D*)` would be fine?

Comment: @CaiusJard You are right, the content is more at the end and there will be less backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if I understood the requirements correctly, but this Regex will capture the last number in the input string, decimal or not, in the first group and the following characters in the second group:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\D*)$
```

So, the input string `"4/8.75LB"` would be split into:

- Group 1: `"8.75"`
- Group 2: `"LB"`